# Указание на содержание справки

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как выразить мысль лучше?

Справка об абонементе в бассейн. 
Справка о том, что я имею абонемент
Справка о том, что я заключил договор с администрацией бассейна.

Возможны ли эти варианты? Какие есть альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Справка о наличии (о приобретении) абонемента в бассейн.

Answer (score 0):

Справка не должна иметь преамбулу. Ниже штампа организации, после названия документа — *СПРАВКА* — она имеет следующую форму: *выдана гр. NN в том, что он заключил Договор №... о посещении...*

И далее: *Дана для предоставления в Отдел кадров вуза*.

Answer (score -1):

Сам абонемент - пропуск в бассейн. Зачем ещё и справка, в дополнение к абонементу?

Comment: Справка предоставляется заведующему кафедрой физической культуры в учебном заведении, чтобы иметь право освобождения от занятий.